# iOS Add UIView below UITableView

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

I have a UITableView, under which (not in the header!) I would like a new UIView. It's done in WhatsApp, in the Chats' tab (I' new in here so I can't add a picture!).

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Regards

Comment: You haven't asked a question.  What have you tried?  Where did you get stuck?

Answer (score 2):

Create a parent UIView to contain you UITableView and the other UIView. Add these views as subviews to the parent view.

Answer (score 2):

**Edited Answer:**

You could do this. Initialize 2 buttons or 2 views in..

In the cellForRowIndexPath :

```
UIView * superView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 45)];
[superView addSubview:view1];
[superView addSubview:view2];

 // You should make sure that CGRectMake of view1 + view 2  = superView //

Check if (indexPath.row == lastRow)
     {
      [cell addSubview: superView]
     }
```

**Original Answer:**

You should use

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section
```

I think the exact answer you are looking for is available  [here !!](http://blog.blackwhale.at/2009/07/uibutton-in-uitableview-footer/)

Comment: yeah way to go Leogolas, you may want to check the delegate method out for the height for the footer, if your having problems viewing the whole uiview, i know i did.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. I definitely do not want to add the UIView in the header or in the footer of the UITableView. What I would like is to reveal the UIView (two UIButton) when I drag down the UITableView. If you have WhatsApp on your iPhone, you can see the behavior of the tableView in the "Chats" tab...

Answer (score -1):

`UITableView` has a [`backgroundView`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006943-CH3-DontLinkElementID_2) property that you can set.